# Ignite CrudRepository still getting name conflict for deleteAll

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, ignite

I using ignite core, and ignite-spring-data both 2.7.0

```
 compile "org.apache.ignite:ignite-core:2.7.0"
 compile "org.apache.ignite:ignite-spring-data:2.7.0"
 compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:2.1.5.RELEASE');
```

But I still get this error:

```
error: name clash: deleteAll(Iterable<? extends T>) in CrudRepository and deleteAll(Iterable<ID>) in IgniteRepository have the  same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
where T,ID are type-variables:
T extends Object declared in interface CrudRepository
ID extends Serializable declared in interface IgniteRepository
```

According to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-6879 this issue was resolved with version 2.7.0 so why am I still getting it?

if I use instead:

```
  compile "org.apache.ignite:ignite-spring-data_2.0:2.7.0"
```

It seems to break everything, so I am not sure that an option.

```
import org.apache.ignite.springdata.repository.IgniteRepository;
import org.apache.ignite.springdata.repository.config.Query;
import org.apache.ignite.springdata.repository.config.RepositoryConfig;


@RepositoryConfig(cacheName = "PersonCache")
public interface PersonRepository extends IgniteRepository<Person, Long> {

 List<Person> findByFirstNameAndLastName(String firstName, String lastName);

 @Query("SELECT c.* FROM Person p JOIN \"ContactCache\".Contact c ON p.id=c.personId WHERE p.firstName=? and p.lastName=?")
List<Contact> selectContacts(String firstName, String lastName);

 @Query("SELECT p.id, p.firstName, p.lastName, c.id, c.type, c.location FROM Person p JOIN \"ContactCache\".Contact c ON p.id=c.personId WHERE p.firstName=? and p.lastName=?")
List<List<?>> selectContacts2(String firstName, String lastName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just switch to new 2.0 support version of ignite spring data.

```
compile "org.apache.ignite:ignite-spring-data_2.0:${igniteVersion}"

import org.apache.ignite.springdata20.repository.IgniteRepository;
import org.apache.ignite.springdata20.repository.config.Query;
import org.apache.ignite.springdata20.repository.config.RepositoryConfig;
```

No worries!

Answer (score 1):

After changing to use:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-spring-data_2.0</artifactId>
        <version>${ignite.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

.....

```
<ignite.version>2.7.0</ignite.version>
```

You will have to re-import everything. so just delete the 'import' part from the code all together. Since now the IgniteRepository etc are coming from a package called org.apache.ignite.springdata20.repository .... instead of the old one.